# Explorer for Substrate-based EVM chains

Tags: evm, frontier, explorer

I've built an EVM-compatible blockchain using Substrate and connected it with Metamask and PolkadotJs explorer. But I want a more user-friendly explorer that users with a non-technical background can also use to view their transactions, like etherscan. Are there any open-source explorers out there that are compatible with Substrate-based EVM chains?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried connecting any evm explorers to the RPC?

Comment: Yep, I've connected Epirus and Expedition @DanShields

Comment: Nice. Successful? If so, I think you could answer your own question with some suggestions :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is an [open source](https://github.com/blockscout/blockscout) indexer and explorer called [Blockscout](https://www.blockscout.com/), which is fairly user-friendly. You can use for your Substrate-based EVM chain.

Here are some examples of its usage by [Moonbeam](https://blockscout.moonbeam.network/) parachain and [CloudWalk](https://explorer.mainnet.cloudwalk.io/) solochain.